# Block everything except some ports and specific IP Addresses, server can't do HTTP GET

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables, firewall

I can't get this `firewall.sh` script to work. It currently doesn't allow me to get a file at 'https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images' so either my DNS is flawed or I am blocking something I am not aware of is needed.

My goal is to allow server1 to communicate with the world only via HTTP,HTTPS,DNS,ICMP and make Git-Pulls/Pushs but only communicate with specific servers via MONGODB (27017). Everything else should be blocked.

```
#reset everything previously
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X

# DRop everything execpt outgoing
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# make exceptions for ssh && http && dns
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport dns -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport dns -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT
#GIT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9418 -j ACCEPT
#allow icmp
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT


#HOSTS-INTERCOMMUNICATION FIREWALL
declare -a friendlyHosts=("176.2.2.2" "188.1.1.1" "133.4.4.4")
iptables -N privilege # create a new chain
for i in "${friendlyHosts[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
    iptables -A privilege --src "$i" -j ACCEPT
done

#mongodb
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 27017 -j privilege
iptables -I FORWARD -m tcp -p tcp --dport 27017 -j privilege

iptables -A privilege -j DROP  # drop everyone else


iptables-save
```

This script locks me out of my server. Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing `dport` and `sport`.

For instance if you want to get back DNS replies, this :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport dns -j ACCEPT
```

Should be :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport dns -j ACCEPT
```

You made this mistake almost everywhere.